# Convert SQL query to Sequilize

Tags: sql, count, sequelize.js

This is my SQL query, I want to convert this query to sequelize query:

```
SELECT 
    `users`.`uId`, `users`.*, 
    COUNT(`tasks`.`userUId`) AS 'tasksCount' 
FROM 
    `users` AS `users` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `tasks` AS `tasks` ON `users`.`uId` = `tasks`.`userUId` 
GROUP BY 
    `users`.`uId`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sequelize.fn` in the `attrubutes` option and indicate `users.id` in `group` option:

```js
const users = await Users.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include:[[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('tasks.userId')), 'tasksCount']]
  },
  include: [{
    model: Tasks,
    attributes: ['userId']
  }],
  group: [Sequelize.col('tasks.userId')]
})
```